# Cannot make working Spring + Hibernate Pessimistic Locking

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE with Hibernate 5.0.11.Final on a MySql RDS instance.

Multiple request can arrive to a controller, also concurrent, and i cannot manage the concurrency...

This is the controller method part

```
Interruttore interruttore = interruttoreService.findById(idInterruttore);
                if (!interruttore.isManuale()) { 
                    if(!interruttore.isStato()){

//                  logger.debug("Switch off, turn it on");
                    interruttoreService.toggleSwitchNew(interruttore);
                    }
```

I would like the second concurrent call to the controller will not go into `interruttoreService.toggleSwitchNew(interruttore);` so I thought of Pessimistic Locking strategy.
First of all `interruttoreService.findById(idInterruttore);` is a service class which calls a dao function:

```
public Interruttore findById(int id) {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
        criteria.setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).add(Restrictions.eq("idInterruttore", id));
        return (Interruttore) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

`toggleSwitchNew` is

```
@Override
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
public void toggleSwitchNew(Interruttore interruttore) {

        Date nextTimeout = interruttore.getTimeoutDate();
        Date date = new Date();
        Date now = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        if (nextTimeout == null) {
            nextTimeout = now;
        }
        boolean on = interruttore.isStato();
        int idInterruttore = interruttore.getIdInterruttore();
        String pinName = interruttore.getPinName();
        GpioPinDigitalOutput relePin = interruttore.getGpio()
                    .provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.getPinByName(pinName));
            try {
                updateInterruttore(idInterruttore, now, !on);

                String log = getLogStatus(!on) + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore();
                logger.debug(log);
                relePin.high();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error("Errore sleep ", e);
                }
                relePin.low();
            } catch (GpioPinExistsException ge) {
                logger.error("Gpio già esistente");
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                logger.error("generic error", t);
            } finally {

                interruttore.getGpio().unprovisionPin(relePin);
            }

    }
```

And `updateInterruttore` which I think it's the last problem comes from this DAO method

```
@Override
public void updateInterruttore(int idInterruttore, Date timeout, boolean stato) {

        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        String update = "update Interruttore i set i.timeoutDate = :timeout, i.stato = :stato where idInterruttore = :idInterruttore";
        session.createQuery(update).setDate("timeout", timeout).setBoolean("stato", stato)
                .setInteger("idInterruttore", idInterruttore).setLockOptions(LockOptions.UPGRADE).executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
    }
```

I am still experiencing concurrent access to the controller and situations where my Interruttore gets updated and switched on twice in less than a second...

Comment: That code shouldn't be in the controller but in a service layer in which it will use a single transaction instead of multiple.

Comment: which code? the first i posted?

Comment: The code that is in your controller. That should be service code...